# elasticsearch nested query arrays

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index data like this in 'es'

```
"hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "nginx_logs_2020-10.25",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "NJ9vXnUB4raIoC_Ij4uU",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@version" : "1",
          "host" : "elk",
          "@timestamp" : "2020-10-25T06:26:11.171Z",
          "message" : """100.121.99.174 [23/Oct/2020:04:25:54 +0800] "HEAD / HTTP/1.0" 200 0 "-" "-" 100.121.99.174 0.000 -""",
          "tags" : [
            "_grokparsefailure",
            "_geoip_lookup_failure"
          ],
          "path" : "/var/log/nginx/access_2020-10-23.log"
        }
      }
]}
```

I just want to query the tags array for data with '**_grokparsefailure**' in it.
How to write the query statement? Please help me. Thank you.
**the app version is follow this:**

- elasticsearch:7.6.x

this index mapping is follow this:

```
{
  "nginx_logs_2020-10.25" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "dynamic" : "false",
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "@version" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        },
        "agent" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "bytes" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "clientip" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        },
        "geoip" : {
          "properties" : {
            "city_name" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            },
            "continent_code" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            },
            "country_code2" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            },
            "country_code3" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            },
            "country_name" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            },
            "ip" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            },
            "latitude" : {
              "type" : "half_float"
            },
            "location" : {
              "type" : "geo_point"
            },
            "longitude" : {
              "type" : "half_float"
            },
            "region_code" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            },
            "region_name" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            },
            "timezone" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "host" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        },
        "http_x_forwarded_for" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        },
        "httpversion" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        },
        "params" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "referrer" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "request" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "request_duration" : {
          "type" : "float"
        },
        "response" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        },
        "upstream_request_duration" : {
          "type" : "float"
        },
        "useragent" : {
          "properties" : {
            "build" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            },
            "device" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            },
            "name" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            },
            "os" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            },
            "os_major" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            },
            "os_minor" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            },
            "os_name" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "verb" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this is a nginx log templte,this is the template I specified when I imported the data using Logstash,I didn't delete the wrong data when parsing the data,So now I want to delete the data with '_grokparsefailure' in the tags field.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) that returns documents that contain one
> or more exact terms in a provided field.

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "@version": "1",
  "host": "elk",
  "@timestamp": "2020-10-25T06:26:11.171Z",
  "tags": [
    "_grokparsefailure",
    "_geoip_lookup_failure"
  ],
  "path": "/var/log/nginx/access_2020-10-23.log"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
     {
      "query": {
        "terms": {
          "tags": [ "_grokparsefailure" ]
        }
      }
    }
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "64522118",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "@version": "1",
          "host": "elk",
          "@timestamp": "2020-10-25T06:26:11.171Z",
          "tags": [
            "_grokparsefailure",
            "_geoip_lookup_failure"
          ],
          "path": "/var/log/nginx/access_2020-10-23.log"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Update 1:**

You can delete the documents that match the specified query, using [delete by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html)

```
POST /index-name/_delete_by_query

{
  "query": {
     "terms": {
      "tags": [
        "_grokparsefailure"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I followed your statement, but the query is empty.

Comment: @Leandy can you please share your index mapping? I have added a working example and tried it locally also.

Comment: it just a nginx log template, I just saved the wrong results when I entered the data,now I want delete the data with tags

Comment: Please see the template provided above, thank your help.

Comment: @Leandy sorry I have never worked with nginx log template, so I am not quite familiar with this :( But I am not able to find any mapping for the `tags` field in your index mapping template. Please go through my updated answer, that may help you to delete the data with tags

Answer (score 0):

problem was solved.The reason is my setup with 'mappings'. the attributes 'dynamic' is 'false'.It means that if a new field can be added successfully, it cannot be retrieved.